# Pause button java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to set "pause" button in order to pause my thread  if I clicked in the first time .If I hit the button another time the thread should be resumed .I set a boolean "marche" it should controls my thread every time I changed it.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PauseButton {
   static int count = 0;
   static boolean marche = true;
   static Thread mythread;
   static JButton button = new JButton("Pause");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame fen = new JFrame("EDT");
      fen.getContentPane().add(button);
      fen.setSize(200, 100);
      fen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      fen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      fen.setVisible(true);
      updateBouton();
      setButtonLis();
   }

   public static void updateBouton() {
      mythread = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
               while (marche) {
                  try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  button.setText("Pause " + ++count);
               }
            }
         }
      };

      mythread.start();

   }

   static public void setButtonLis() {

      button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

         @Override
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            if (marche)
               marche = false;
            else
               marche = true;
            new Thread() {
               public void run() {
                  System.out.print(marche + " ");
               }
            }.start();
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
         }

         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // button.setText("Pause");
         }
      });

   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to pause the counting but I couldn't (after pressing the button)

Comment: Please re-format your code. If you study, understand and follow standard Java formatting and naming rules, you will find it much easier to understand other folk's code, and we will find it much easier to understand your code.

Comment: I re-format my code ,I tryed my best :P

Comment: is there any significance of looping over 0 to 99? do you want it continue from where it left off ? when you toggle?  -- any particular reason to have two threads creations? one in update and one in mouse listener?

Comment: I'm  just discovering thread ,it 's just an example...

Comment: Code re-formatted. Please do yourself and especially us a big favor, and read up on Java code formatting standards. Random indentations make your code very difficult to read, and it's not in your best interest to make your question any harder than it has to be to answer.

Comment: Note myself, I'd use a Swing Timer for this and would not directly use threads. This would **greatly** simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `updateBouton` code to the following...

```
public static void updateBouton() {
    th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
//            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(marche) {
                        bouton.setText("Pause " + ++count);
                    }
                }
//            }
        }
    };
    th.start();
}
```

when you click on button then variable `marche` was false so the while loop in thread closes and thread completed its execution so make a infinite while loop and check boolean to update text on button..also there is no need for the `for(int i=0;i<100;i++)` loop..

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you're looking for.
    public class Start {

```
    public static WhateverThread thread;
    public static boolean isPaused = false;

    public static void main(String...strings){
        thread = new WhateverThread();
        thread.start(); 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("pausebutton test");

        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();

        content.setSize(frame.getSize());
        content.setLayout(null);

        JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");

        pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isPaused) {
                    thread.resumeThread();
                    System.out.println("Thread runs");
                } else {
                    try {
                        thread.pauseThread();
                        System.out.println("Thread waits");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                isPaused = !isPaused;
            }

        });
        content.add(pause);
        pause.setLocation(10, 10);
        pause.setSize(100, 20);
        frame.add(content);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class WhateverThread extends Thread{

        private boolean isRunning = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("I am running...");
        }

        public void pauseThread() throws InterruptedException
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        public void resumeThread()
        {
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The classes and variables are only made static because this is a quick and dirty snippet and I wanted to call everything from within the main Method.